# Troubles with closing div when clicking background using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, web

I am having problems with closing a **div** container and reverting back to the pages original state when I click outside of it. I have tried pretty much every solution on stackoverflow and have looked all over the internet and cannot find or think of a solution. I have tried using stopPropogation and what happens is that whenever I click the background after the first time, it still toggles the **div** container. Here is a stripped down version of my code in js fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/10545/

Here is the jquery

```
    <script> 
var text = 1;




$(' .login1').click(function(e){
     $('.div2, .div3, .patientAccess').toggle("fast");
     $('.loginform_hidden').toggleClass('loginform_visible ');


    if(text == 1){

        $(".div1").toggleClass("animateSlide col-xs-12");
        $('.login1').html('Go Back');
        $('.imageOne').toggleClass('animateSlideTop');
        // If an event gets to the body



        text = 0;
    } else{
        $(".div1").toggleClass("animateSlide");
        $('.login1').html('Start Animation');
         $('.imageOne').toggleClass('animateSlideTop');
          // If an event gets to the body


        text = 1;
    }
});


$('.login2').click(function(){
    $('.registrationform_hidden').toggleClass('registrationform_visible ');
        $('.div1, .div3, .patientAccess').toggle("fast");
    $('.imageOne').toggleClass('animateSlideTop');
    if(text == 1){
        $(".div2").toggleClass("animateSlide2");
        $('.login2').html('Go Back');

        text = 0;
    } else{
        $(".div2").toggleClass("animateSlide2");
        $('.login2').html('Start Animation');

        text = 1;
    }
});


$('.div3').click(function(){
    $('.imageOne').toggleClass('animateSlideTop');
        $('.div1, .div2, .patientAccess').toggle("fast");
    if(text == 1){
        $(".div3").toggleClass("animateSlide3");
        $('.div3').html('Go Back');


        text = 0;
    } else{
        $(".div3").toggleClass("animateSlide3");
        $('.div3').html('Start Animation');

        text = 1;
    }
});
      </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think i understood your question right.

Add an event listener for catching clicks outside the highlighted div and remove the highlighted class from that highlighted div using .removeClass() on clicking anywhere outside that particular div.

I guess i understood & answered your ques. Do respond for this. Hope it works.

Comment: I have tried this method. That removes the class but the original classes(divs) do not re-appear.